# Planar intersections of constant Gauss curvature K surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Have they been studied? It appears they did not generate enough interest except the conic sections $K=0$. Do they give rise to curves of fourth order?

Comment: Haven't checked carefully, but offhand I'd guess that a general planar section of a non-spherical surface of constant, non-zero Gaussian curvature is not an algebraic curve at all. (That's definitely true for $K = 0$: Take a cylinder over an arbitrary regular curve.)

Comment: Indeed.  its (non-linear?) ODE may be interesting